# trying to place a bullet • in my submenu of my navigation bar using 'â€¢'

Tags: html, css, xml, unicode

Hi all want to insert a bullet (•) in my sub-menu of my navigation bar to separate sub menu items.  I have done this before and it has worked for some reason isn't working for me now. I used 'â€¢'to create a bullet in my css file, however on the webpage all i get is â€¢ instead of •. I am using the code below

```
  .top-nav .sub-menu li:before{
    content:'â€¢';
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:3px 3px 0;
  }
```

am fairly new to this, thanks for your help.

Comment: Use Unicode or HTML entity instead? [**Link**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm)..although `list-style:disc` should work too.

Comment: Try adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` to your <head>-Tag if not done already.

Comment: by default u get a bullet when u use `<ul><li>Abc</li><li>GGG</li></ul>`

Answer (score 2):

If you are deliberately using the three characters a-circumflex, euro-sign, cent-sign to represent a bullet character, then you are relying on the fact that your editor thinks the file is in one encoding (Latin-1 or cp1252 perhaps), and CSS thinks it is in another (UTF-8). That's not a good way to be working, it can only lead to grief.

Either use an editor that understands UTF-8 to edit your CSS, or make sure the CSS only contains ASCII characters. There might be other ways, but I think the simplest/safest way to represent non-ASCII characters in CSS is probably to use a hex escape sequence such as `\0026`

Comment: +1. Note that the CSS escape sequence for the `•` character would be `\2022`: http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#1%E2%80%A2

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that you changed something with the treatment of the encoding of your file.

In order to make your example work, you have to be using an editor that does not use UTF-8 encoding when writing the file. If you declare the charset of your document to be utf-8 in the html head, the browser will interpret the bytes written by your editor as UTF-8 thus showing • instead.

Did you change your editor or the settings? If it uses UTF-8 now, that implicit conversion won't work anymore, but you can instead just put • in your CSS.

Or did you declare another charset for your document this time (or none at all)? In that case, the browser will just treat the file as it is and display the three characters instead. Try to add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

to your document's head.